# Dual Power supply from a Single supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

Currently i am doing a circuit for achieving voltage regulation. Please refer below for the same.

[image]

I am looking for a split voltage supply design using a single supply.

On No-Load i am getting the split supply across the zener and the remaining voltage across the resistor.

But upon loading the situation changes,as the load resistor intervenes with the 25 Ohm and the voltage drops. A figure for the same is given below:
[image]

The Load will not be present simultaneously as i am using this supply for IGBT ON/OFF. So the voltage split is bizarre when individual loads are removed or connected.

I understand that there are IC's for performing this function of creating a dual voltage from single supply, but i am looking a cost effective one. This is one reason i went with this conventional way .

Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your load current requirements are in mA region (e.g. 1-5mA) then I recommend [ICL7660](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7660.pdf). For higher currents, you can still build a regulator like in the 1st picture, but using a PNP transistor with the output of ICL7660 as a ref. voltage.

Comment: Yes it will work, But there are four such requirements, so using an IC everywhere is not feasible.  Thanks for the reply..